# How to use Intent in custom ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-intent

I want to use Intent in the `MainActivity`.
I want when I click the `ListView` item transferred to other `Activity` .
I using custom `ListView`.
This custom `ListView` create ٌwith training site below :

https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html

**Custom ListView :**

```
package mypackage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   
String [] result;
Context context;
int [] imageId;
  private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public CustomAdapter(mainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList,     int[] prgmImages) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    result=prgmNameList;
    context=mainActivity;
    imageId=prgmImages;
     inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
             getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return result.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView tv;
    ImageView img;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;       
         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
         holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);       
     holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
     holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);         
     rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });   
    return rowView;
}
```

}

**Main Activity :**

```
package mypackage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView lv;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new     AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int     position, long id) {   
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,     SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
    }
    });
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

Update your CustomAdapter.java

```
package mypackage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{   
String [] result;
Context context;
int [] imageId;
  private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
public CustomAdapter(mainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList,     int[] prgmImages) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    result=prgmNameList;
    context=mainActivity;
    imageId=prgmImages;
     inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
             getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return result.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

public class Holder
{
    TextView tv;
    ImageView img;
}
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Holder holder=new Holder();
    View rowView;       
         rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
         holder.tv=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         holder.img=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);       
     holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
     holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);         
     rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(context, "You Clicked "+result[position], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SecondActivity.class);
         startActivity(i);    
        }
    });   
    return rowView;
}
```